# Why is my jQuery callback function not responding?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

With this code I would expect `called back` prompted in my face but instead I get nothing.

I have followed the simple examples used in tutorials like [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/) and see no apparent different from their examples to mine. Still no success.

```
$.fn.mirror = function (selector, callback) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $selector = $(selector);
        $this.bind('keyup', function () {
            $selector.text($this.val()); 
        });
    });
    callback();
};

$('#displayurl').mirror('.displayurl', function () {
    alert('called back');
});
```

Comment: Because your `callback` call is placed **after** `return`, so this code line is never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are returning after the first line executes. `return` ends the execution of a function and returns the value to the caller.

In this case your callback function will not execute because you are returning `$.each` function and terminating the execution of the function. Try

```
$.fn.mirror = function (selector, callback) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $selector = $(selector);
        $this.bind('keyup', function () {
            $selector.text($this.val()); 
        });
    });
    callback();
    return; //you could return whatever is useful for you if you want.
};

$('#displayurl').mirror('.displayurl', function () {
    alert('called back');
});
```

And I would also suggest you read up on basics of programming.